# Does the Bible make any allusions to life on other planets?

Tags: biblical-basis, extra-terrestrial-life

What, if anything, does the Bible say either supporting the theory of life on other planets, or suggesting that there is none?

Comment: At the time of the Bible's authorship, the notion of "other planets" would not have made sense - even the true nature of *this* planet was barely understood. I'm not sure that the question can really make sense in a Biblical context. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: A fair point, however, I would submit that a) the Bible has provided wisdom on topics that were not understood at the time, b) the Bible might make a claim that would exclude the possibility of ET life without knowing about it or explicitly mentioning it.

Comment: good point, a statement in the negative would be a good answer to the question; any speculation on Biblical text to the positive would be more subjective / interpretive, I suspect

Comment: @user additionally, you might want to look at the thinkings of the "flat earth society". I won't remark on their views, but they, of *anyone*, have done the most Biblical study on the topic.

Comment: @Marc: Flat earth theory?  *Really?*  You do know that that has nothing whatsoever to do with Christianity or Biblical beliefs, don't you?  The belief doesn't appear anywhere in the historical record until the 19th century, where it was created out of whole cloth by a writer and applied retroactively to a work of historical fiction with the purpose of slandering Christians.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The origins of flat earth theory are entirely independent of the research that has been done by proponents of the theory. Many of them count themselves among Christians and have done extensive attempts at justifications employing biblical and other Christianity-related references (whether or not those attempts have been successful or not is another subject, but I see nothing directly problematic with the recommendation to look into their research; if only as a starting point to see what others have considered as possible interpretations of texts.

Answer (score 12):

The Bible really doesn't have anything to say on the subject one way or another.

Historical writings suggest that some of early Christians believed that this world is only one of many that God has created, and particularly among [Gnostic sects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosticism) there were all sorts of interesting ideas on the subject, (for example, that the many worlds that God had created all had free interactions with each other, but not with us because this world was under quarantine, as no other people out of all God's creations were evil enough to murder their own Lord), but whatever the source of these ideas is, it's not found in the Bible.

Comment: Interesting information I'd never heard before... can you provide some references?

Comment: @Flimzy: It's been quite a while since I read about that.  I'll see if I can find the source again...

Comment: So according to the Gnostics, did (1) Christ die multiple times (one for each planet), or (2) somehow they did not sin and thus did not need redemption, or (3) God decided to not save those other planets? :-)

Answer (score 4):

The only verse I have ever heard being taken to mean this is John 10:16 - and that was humorously, not seriously.

> And other sheep I have, which are not of this fold: them also I must
>   bring, and they shall hear my voice; and there shall be one fold, and
>   one shepherd.

Comment: Interesting interpretation... and I think I agree... it's best used humorously in the context of ET life :)

Comment: Seems the obvious interpretation is non Jewish people, although mormons may beg to differ

Comment: I'm pretty sure that aliens are non Jewish people :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the Bible is silent on the question of life that lives somewhere other than earth, with one exception -- angels.

Several passages in the Bible refer to the stars of heaven and the angels interchangeably, and other passages discuss angels in heaven or cast out of heaven to the earth.

[Genesis 28:12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2028:12&version=KJV), [Judges 5:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%205:20&version=KJV), [Job 38:7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2038:7&version=KJV), [Psalm 8:4-5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%208:4-5&version=KJV), [Psalm 147:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20147:4&version=KJV), [Matthew 18:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2018:10&version=KJV), [Matthew 22:30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2022:30&version=KJV), [Matthew 24:29-30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:29-30&version=KJV), [Mark 13:25-26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2013:25-26&version=KJV), [Revelation 1:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%201:20&version=KJV), [Revelation 12:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012:4&version=KJV)

> **[Revelation 12:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012:9&version=KJV)** (KJV)
>   <sup>9</sup>  And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and **Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him**.

My understanding is that such passages have led to a popular belief that every star (especially the "morning star" and similar stars later redefined as "planets") has an associated angel, much like Matthew 18:10 leads to the popular belief that every child has a guardian angel.

(This idea -- that each planet has at least one angel associated with it -- and other ideas that [Mason Wheeler mentions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1060/30) -- is a big part of C. S. Lewis's fictional trilogy beginning with "[Out of the Silent Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Silent_Planet)").

Comment: This is actually a great and relevant answer, but I think it could be improved by noting that what official position these ideas have in relation to major Christian traditions. In other words, are these folk religion ideas, are they official in any specific sects or do they have a place in orthodox Christianity?

Answer (score 3):

The Bible as we have it doesn't give an absolute answer to the idea of life on other planets.  I say "as we have it" simply because [the books of the bible have changed throughout history.](http://www.biblestudytools.com/bible-study/topical-studies/who-decided-what-went-into-the-bible.html)

Some argue that John 10:16 and first chapter of Ezekiel suggest life outside our planet and even possible visitation.

Others would argue that the omission of life being created on other planets in the creation story of Genesis proves we're the only planet with sentient life.

But why write about something that doesn't pertain to our personal walk with Christ?  Telling us how others live for Him and worship Him on other planets would probably be something we couldn't comprehend.  "For now we see through a glass darkly" [(1 Cor 13:12)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Cor+13%3A12&version=KJV)

But God wants to be worshiped [(Deut 6:1-5)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=Deuteronomy%206). If this is the case, is it really far-fetched to think He would use the vast universe He created to hold a host of worlds that should worship Him?

Our limited minds have a hard time wrapping around the idea that there could be life on other planets that God also attends to.  Many believe that since all the universe lives in sin [(Rom 8:18-25)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=Romans%208) it suggests that Jesus would have to die repeatedly for each planet where sentient life exists.  But the Bible states that "whosoever believes in him should not perish" [(John 3:16)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=John%203) and that "by grace are ye saved through faith." [(Eph 2:8)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=Ephesians%202)

Is it that hard to believe that God could decide to show another world His grace in a different way?  Perhaps the sacrifice of life doesn't hold the same impact to them.
I'm quite certain that God knows better than us what would get the message of His love and desire that none should perish across to others better than our limited minds would ever be able to fathom.

Or perhaps those other worlds still practice animal sacrifice as it was before the death of Christ.  Perhaps those other worlds will experience a different thing to take them from animal sacrifice to salvation through faith and grace without that sacrifice.

Yes, the last part is just a guess ...  an opinion.  But it is not our place to say what method God can or cannot use to bring people to Him.  It is foolish of us to limit Him.  [Ecclesiastes 8:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=Ecclesiastes%208) states "Then I saw all that God has done. No one can comprehend what goes on under the sun. Despite all his efforts to search it out, man cannot discover its meaning. Even if a wise man claims he knows, he cannot really comprehend it."

If we can't comprehend what goes on here on our own planet, how can we possibly hope to comprehend what God is doing with the rest of His universe?  I am sure the debate could go on indefinitely as to whether or not life exists on other planets.  And while it's perhaps fun to debate such things, it definitely should not be our focus. "I press on toward the goal to win the prize for which God has called me heavenward in Christ Jesus" [(Phil 3:14)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=Philippians%203).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that some Christian groups do believe that there are planets with life on them and they are not affected by sin. I think SDA believe this.

Answer (score 2):

I think Pastor Doug makes a great case for life on other worlds: 
http://www.amazingfacts.org/news-and-features/news/id/528/bible-answers-with-pastor-doug.aspx

He highlights the idea that perhaps were the one fallen planet of many:
“What man of you, having an hundred sheep, if he loses one of them, doth not leave the ninety and nine in the wilderness, and go after that which is lost, until he find it?” (Luke 15:4).

I wanted to respond to Wikis comments as well:
--------"I think it is unlikely that God created life outside Earth for two reasons:
- Scientific: because of the Fermi paradox which says essentially that if there is extra terrestrial life we should have seen evidence of it by now.
- Theological: because Jesus died once only (Hebrews 10:10). So if there are aliens, would they need redemption? Apparently the answer is "Yes", if they have freewill. However, since Jesus has already died here on Earth, He couldn't die again for them. Therefore aliens with freewill cannot exist (though animal life might)."-------------

- Scientific - The universe is vast - in our Milky Way Galaxy there 1 million x 1 million star systems, then there are 1 million x 1 million galaxies - we're talking near infinite numbers, and with the speed of light we are seeing 'evidence' from millions of years ago (if a star is 1 million light years away we're seeing light from it 1 million years old, so considering the massive scale of the universe we're only seeing 'recent' events from stars nearby that are say 50 years old (50 light years away). Basically if anyone exists right now but they're on the other side of the galaxy, it's impossible to see what's happening let alone another Galaxy right now, and they can't see us either (if they exist). Even if you could see evidence of galactic scale engineering, if they're building it now and they're 100 light years away (a relative neighbour) or 1 million light years away, we won't see that evidence for another 100 or 1 million years respectively. Of course for them to travel here, means a colossal expenditure of resources and time (unless they've invented the Warp Drive). But they'd have to know we were here in the first place...if somehow they did find out about us, then it's still doubtful it would be worth the trip. So I kind of agree with Paster Doug that perhaps there's a galactic restriction around us, or God may well have placed us so far away from any other life that the sheer impracticalities of travel and discovering each other places nearly insurmountable barriers between us all so no 'mystical' barrier is needed.
- Theological - we are taught in the Bible that each of us is special, as pastor Doug points out perhaps he's come after the lost people. There's nothing to say each and every race isn't special. It's quite possible Jesus died only once for each of us, or that they didn't need redemption because by one method or another they don't have free will (though it may not feel like that to them). Working on a lot of science fiction projects it's easy to imagine many worlds where this could be the norm. A society of machines with the rules hardcoded in not to break them, yet still with the apparent 'free will' to worship God and his creation. Let's try not to go around in circles though. In Jesus's teaching we learn that he has died for us, you, me - personally for us, so I feel in a sense that on a galatic scale he too could have singled out our world as a sacrifice, perhaps as a demonstration to the rest of the universe (if they know) of his all powerful love. Imagine billions of worlds full of life (and not necessarily intelligent, there could be millions with just unintelligent creatures) perhaps trillions of worlds of life, billions of trillions of living souls, how great his love for us then, how great his sacrifice to save this one sheep amongst the enormous flock in the heavens.

So to imagine just our world, just our few billion people, seems to diminish God's power in the universe and just increase my sense of self worth, when I would rather imagine a God who  is unlimited in his creation.

*And finally, am I the only Christian who would grin stupidly if the first friendly aliens we met turned out to have red skin, horns and a tail? And were ever so holy! :-) I'd love God to turn our terrible preconceptions on their heads!*

Comment: Welcome to C.Se. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).  This is a good start.  It's very chatty and "forum-like," almost to the point of not answering the question (ahem), but by linking to a sermon and trying to brinng it back to theology, I can definitely see that you are trying!  In the future, I'd suggest a little more heft in the sources you use, and better explanation of what denomination "Pastor Doug" would speak for.  All in all, it's *ok*

Answer (score 1):

The Bible makes no obvious reference to aliens, and most people (including myself) think it makes no reference *at all* to aliens.

I think it is unlikely that God created life outside Earth for two reasons:

1. **Scientific:** because of the **[Fermi paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox)** which says essentially that if there is extra terrestrial life we should have seen evidence of it by now.
2. **Theological:** because Jesus died **once only** ([Hebrews 10:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%2010:10&version=NIV)). So if there are aliens, would they need redemption? Apparently the answer is "Yes", if they have freewill. However, since Jesus has already died here on Earth, He couldn't die again for them. Therefore aliens with freewill cannot exist (though animal life might).

Comment: The Fermi paradox is a bit more subtle than "we should have seen evidence of it by now", and is a topic of active research (indeed, as a race we have been capable of such for only a tiny fragment of time). It would seem questionable to suggest this as overly strong evidence in *either* direction. Or at best, it only makes sense to do so when the audience is well-versed in the science and able to make a professionally-based reasoning of it (i.e. in discussion with astrophysicists)

Comment: For once I agree with Marc here.  If I understand correctly, it was only a few months ago that we detected the first *potential* evidence of the existence of another planet sufficiently Earth-like to be capable of supporting life as we know it. And that's very, very far away, and the scientists aren't sure yet if it's a real Earth-like planet or not.

Comment: Don't animals have free will?

Comment: I disagree with this.   Deuteronomy 14:21 (KJV) specifically mentions that the Israelites may sell meat to aliens ;)  (maybe this was to protect them from their mis-interpretting the alien book: "To Serve Man").

Comment: @user729 anamals may have free will in a sense, however they are not free moral agents. They are incapable of making a moral decision (ie, killing another animal would not be considered murder).

Comment: Regarding point 2, because Christ's atonement on this earth was infinite and eternal, it would not have to be repeated on other worlds for it to be applied there.

Comment: @Samuel - indeed, that is my point. But how would they know about Christ's death on Earth?

Comment: They'd learn about it through prophets, the same as us. And perhaps they would be visited by Christ after his resurrection. We do have the advantage here on earth of historical record agreeing that there most likely was a man named Jesus who lived and influenced a lot of people, but it's simply through the scriptures and prophets that we know, for example, that he was resurrected and that he's our Savior. It might require more faith from them, but God wouldn't leave them on their own. So, basically, I don't think point 2 is an issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think the point of Scripture is to help Man deal with the world around him.  It does this by (briefly) explaining where he came from and documents various interactions between him and his Maker.

Scripture doesn't say there is life on other planets, but it doesn't rule it out either.  It's just not something that mankind needs to address day-to-day.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.