# What does the Bible say about aliens? Did God create any life outside Earth?

Tags: creation, extra-terrestrial-life

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [Does the Bible make any allusions to life on other planets?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/does-the-bible-make-any-allusions-to-life-on-other-planets)

God created us in His own image, we can be proud that we are His privileged creations in this Earth. But are we unique in this universe? 
I believe that God has kept rest of the Universe for us to praise His wisdom and wonders and to praise his creations which are limitless. We will not be able achieve/find anything beyond this fascination. Even if there are 'people' in some other galaxies, we do not have the privileges  to find them. 
But I know my faith related to this has no base. 
So, what does the Bible say about this? Any support to my belief?

Comment: This is *not* an exact duplicate. The other question is specifically about what the Bible says. This one asks whether God has created life off Earth. My answer (below) fits here - not there.

Comment: @Wiki At Area 51: I think your answer would fit on the other one, especially your point #2--especially in light of this one having been closed as a dupe.

Comment: I looked at the other answers, which are good in their own right. If the title of this question as well as it's focus could be changed a little maybe it could be reopened? I'd love to see more answers on this subject. I think everyone wonders about this and the more answers from more biblical perspectives the better.